# How to get array object from html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box how to get all text and value in a array.

```
<select  data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value=""> -- Select Template -- </option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

all the value in a object array

how to get radio button label and value in a array

```
<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="7" onclick="hidetyping_translt()" 
            name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage1" value="English" 
            checked="checked" type="radio"> English </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="8" onclick="showtyping_translt()" 
            name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage2" value="Other" 
            type="radio">Other Language</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="9" onclick="hidetyping_translt()" 
            name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage3" value="Flash" 
            type="radio">Flash SMS</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option I prefer to get data from html elements is the following:

```
(function myFunc() {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
           let selectContainer = document.querySelector(".select")
           let allOptions = selectContainer.querySelectorAll("option")
           allOptions.forEach(option => {
             console.log(option.value)
           })
        })
      }())
```

Please notice above how I loop through the allOptions array and get the value.
You are able to make a newArray on top of the forEach function and use `newArray.push()` to push all the values in an array

```
<select class="select" data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value="">-- Select Template --</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>`
```

I the following code works for your radio example:

```
(function myFunc() {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
           let radioContainer = document.querySelector(".radio")
           let newArray = []
           let allOptions = radioContainer.querySelectorAll("input")
           allOptions.forEach(input => {
             newArray.push(input.value)
           })
           console.log(newArray)
        })
      }())
```

```
<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="7" onclick="hidetyping_translt()" name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage1" value="English" checked="checked" type="radio">
        English
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="8" onclick="showtyping_translt()" name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage2" value="Other" type="radio">
        Other Language
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="9" onclick="hidetyping_translt()" name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage3" value="Flash" type="radio">
        Flash SMS
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear You are using class selecter (let radioContainer = document.querySelector(".radio")) but we require html selecter

Comment: @user1056388, can you please be more specific with "HTML selector"?

Answer (score 0):

Radio Select and Select Option is sort of "one selected at a time" but in any case, you are able to multi-select on the radio or select option, then just do this to the name attribute

```
name="txtSelectedLanguage[]"
```

multiarray would be

```
name="txtSelectedLanguage[][]"
```

Comment: Dear team we write code independent so we are not used selector id,name class.we only use the type or tag name selector

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand the question.
Do you want a JS Array out of the Values and Labels?

Try these:

```js
$(function() {
    var selectObj = {};
    
    // better would be if you have an ID on your select to avoid problems
    $('select option').each(function(k,v){
      selectObj[k] = $(v).html();
    });
    
    console.log(selectObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value="">-- Select Template --</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>`
```

and for your radio buttons (but i dont like the output of your html, thats not really ready to use with JS):

```js
$(function() {
    var radioObj = {};
    
    $('.radio label').each(function(){
      var k = $('input', $(this)).attr('value'),
        v = $(this).text().trim();
      
      radioObj[k] = v;
    });
    
    console.log(radioObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="7" onclick="hidetyping_translt()" name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage1" value="English" checked="checked" type="radio">
        English
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="8" onclick="showtyping_translt()" name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage2" value="Other" type="radio">
        Other Language
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input tabindex="9" onclick="hidetyping_translt()" name="txtSelectedLanguage" id="txtSelectedLanguage3" value="Flash" type="radio">
        Flash SMS
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  it is working ,but we not get element name like     txtSelectedLanguage=   {
  "English": "English",
  "Other": "Other Language",
  "Flash": "Flash SMS"
}

Comment: @user1056388 then maybe your code is different? because click at "run code snippet" and you will see the result. Maybe you have to adjust  the JavaScript? The selectors could differ or the jQuery version? You have to show more that we can find out where the problem is..